# How to force ngx-datatable to resize after Flex wrapper resizes?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm using "ngx-datatable" inside my Angular10 app.  The app is using flex to layout the usual header, sidebar and data area panels.

I have wrapped the ngx-datatable inside a div that has a flex layout.   On opening the app web page, the wrapper div resizes correctly to take up all the available horizontal and vertical space, but the ngx-datatable does not resize to take up all the vertical available space, as shown below

[image]

```
.full-area-grid {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 99% !important;
}

.eis-vbox {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}


<div id="simpleListWrapper" #wrapper class="eis-vbox" >

  <ngx-datatable #simpleListTable id="simpleList"
    class="material striped full-area-grid"
    [rows] = "rows$ | async"
    [columns]="columns"
    [sorts]="sorts"
    [scrollbarV]="true"
    [footerHeight]="50"
    [headerHeight]="50"
    [rowHeight]="40"
    selectionType="checkbox"
    [loadingIndicator]="isloading > 0"
    [scrollbarV]="true"
    [externalPaging]="true"
    [externalSorting]="true"
    [count]="totalRows$ | async"
    [offset]="pageNumber$ | async"
    (page)="setPage($event)"
    (sort)="onSort($event)"
    (select)="onSelect($event)"
  >
  </ngx-datatable>

</div>
```

Viewing how the web page is displayed, the final resize of the wrapper div takes place AFTER the table has rendered itself and fetched data.

I'm wondering is it possible to capture the resize event on the wrapper div and then somehow force a resize on the table?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe calling `window.requestAnimationFrame` in `ngAfterViewInit` does the trick but I'm not sure.

Comment: Also the `recalculate()` method of `ngx-datatable` may help.

Comment: The only way I can get the vertical gap to be fixed is to inject a time delayed 'resize' window event in the ngAfterViewInit method handler.  But what I don't understand is why the table window does not automatically resize when the wrapper div is resized

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old topic but I want to share my solution, hopefully someone will find it helpful.
My layout is using CSS display: grid with two columns but it should work fine with flex too. First column is for the ngx-datatable and the second is for side content that I need to display aside of the table.
The side content is toggleable so the grid toggles between 100% width and about 60% width.

**Solution:**

1. Wraped grid with a container to listen for its size change.
2. Use @ViewChild to find datatable element and trigger its recalculate function that updates the rows/columns sizes
3. Using ResizeObserver to listen for container size change and trigger actions when size change is detected - in this case run datatable recalculate() function

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-reusable-datatable",
  templateUrl: "./reusable-datatable.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./reusable-datatable.component.scss"],
})
export class ReusableDatatableComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('mainDatatableElement') datatable: DatatableComponent;
  
  resizeObserver: ResizeObserver;
  
  recalculateDatatable() { 
    this.datatable.recalculate() 
  };
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(
      this.recalculateDatatable.bind(this)
    );
    const element = document.getElementById('datatable-container');
    if (element) this.resizeObserver.observe(element);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="datatable-container">
    <ngx-datatable
      #mainDatatableElement
    ></ngx-datatable>
</div>
```

It's a barebone, working solution that should work fine with height too. Also, the recalculate in above scenario is running dozens of times so one might thing about throttling or other optimizations as required.
The browser support is decent [CHECK](https://caniuse.com/?search=resizeobserver)